# String acting as code - Java

Tags: java, string, input

I'm trying to give the user the option to write one line of code in my program.
Their input is saved as a String and I need that string to transfer into a line
of code in the eclipse IDE. For example:

`String a = "System.out.println("String code test.");"`

Now I need this String to compile into the program and print out the text.
Is their a way to do this considering when the user inputs the line of code 
the program has already compiled and therefore cannot insert a new line of code?

I know this question is sort of confusing but if anyone can understand this post or had 
a similar problem, I would enjoy hearing feedback.

EDIT:
I have realized that I might be able to use a BufferedWriter to write to a .java file and then just call that class after it has been writen. Can you write to .java files using BufferedWriter?

Comment: Java does not have any form of `eval(` statement. You may be able to get away with JVM tricks and low-level access to the classloader.

Comment: This previous thread may be helpful on "using eval in Java": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to compile a class in Java at runtime. This means you need to put the code line into a seperate java class file and compile this one. You can find an explanation here:

http://java-bytes.blogspot.de/2012/03/compile-java-files-at-runtime.html

Here is another article I found about dynamic code in java:

http://extremejava.tpk.com.br/2008/11/06/dynamic-code-in-java-aka-eval-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeanSHell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Calling_BeanShell_From_Your_Application) or [Compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)